# MUI Cards are not rendering with style

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am importing the `Card` component from MUI but the component does not have any style.

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import CardActions from "@mui/material/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@mui/material/CardContent";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

const bull = (
  <Box
    component="span"
    
    sx={{ display: "inline-block", mx: "2px", transform: "scale(0.8)" }}
  >
    •
  </Box>
);

export default function BasicCard() {
  return (
    <Card sx={{ minWidth: 275 }}>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography sx={{ fontSize: 14 }} color="text.secondary" gutterBottom>
          Word of the Day
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="h5" component="div">
          be{bull}nev{bull}o{bull}lent
        </Typography>
        <Typography sx={{ mb: 1.5 }} color="text.secondary">
          adjective
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="body2">
          well meaning and kindly.
          <br />
          {'"a benevolent smile"'}
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions>
        <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

What the component is supposed to look like:
[MUI Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rebpv.png)

What the component actually looks like:
[Imported Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hWad.png)

How can I add styling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have `text-align: center` set somewhere in the parent. This usually happens when you create a react project with a template like CRA that has some CSS files like [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/9d0369b1fe3260e620b08effcf85f1edefc5d1ea/packages/cra-template/template/src/App.css#L2):

```css
.App {
  text-align: center;
}
```

You can fix it by finding and removing that `text-align` property or reset it in your `Card`:

```
<Card sx={{ minWidth: 275, textAlign: "initial" }}>
```

If what you mean is the dark background, you can achieve it by setting the theme mode to dark:

```
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: "dark"
  }
});
```

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <Card sx={{ minWidth: 275 }}>
    {...}
  </Card>
</ThemeProvider>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: How do I define createTheme? I am getting an undefined error. Where do I import it from?

Comment: @HusnainMehmood you can read the docs [here](https://mui.com/customization/theming/#createtheme-options-args-theme) and have a look at my codesandbox in the answer. Answer updated.

Comment: @HusnainMehmood you can limit the width by changing `minWidth` to `maxWidth` like in my demo.

Comment: Thanks! you were a big help!